# Macros > Column totals

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set as shown below

[image]

The goal is to take the column totals manually (below the row "Total") and take the variance with the system extracted values to validate the accurcy.

I have used the below code to choose the column dynamically and take the totals to automate the process.

```
Sub ColTotals()

'1. Identifying the relevant column, in this case Beg bal
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Cells.Find(What:="Beg bal", After:=Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues _
    , LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=True, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

'2.Assignment of column values
        C_OI = ActiveCell.Column

'Find the last non-blank cell in column B
    lRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Debug.Print (lRow) '

'3. loop to calculate sum from the last row until first row excluding header
            
    Sum_OI = 0

    For i = lRow To C_OI
    Sum_OI = Sum_OI + Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, C_OI).Value

    Next
    Worksheets("Output").Cells(lRow + 2, C_OI).Value = Sum_OI.Value 'At the end of loop, assigns the column total to the required field,
    
    'Take variance to identify for any difference
    Worksheets("Output").Cells(lRow + 2, C_OI).Value = Cells(lRow + 1, C_OI).Value - Cells(lRow, C_OI).Value 'Calculating the difference between Report sum and calculated sum

End Sub
```

However, I'm unable to achieve with the above code, as no output is thrown and also no error message to debug or identify the issue.

Alternative way/correction to the above code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to sum up `A-F` and put the result in the cell below `Total` and then put the difference between the new number and the `Total` in the next cell below?

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes, idea is to sum the column total, i.e Beg bal ( A to F ), however, I'm trying to do it dynamically just by placing the column name in the above code, total should be calculated and difference also to be calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Checking Totals

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ColTotals()
    
    Const wsName As String = "OutPut"
    Const hTitle As String = "Beg bal"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim hCell As Range
    Set hCell = ws.Cells.Find(hTitle, , xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows)
    If hCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' header not found
    
    Dim Col As Long: Col = hCell.Column
    Dim fRow As Long: fRow = hCell.Row + 1
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = fRow To lRow - 1
        Total = Total + ws.Cells(r, Col).Value
    Next
    
    ws.Cells(lRow + 1, Col).Value = Total
    ws.Cells(lRow + 2, Col).Value = Total - ws.Cells(lRow, Col).Value

End Sub
```